# Change the colour of the text UITextField to the colour typed in it

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uicolor

I have a `UITextView` and I need to detect the `String` which will be a colour that the user has typed in it. Then I need to change the colour of the text in the `UITextField` to the colour typed by the user.

For example: if I type 'red' in the `textField`, the colour of the text should change to red.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? What does your code look like?

Comment: @ZGski I have only created a basic layout for the textfield and connected outlet to it. Confused as to how to approach it.

Comment: Honestly, I think it would benefit everyone if you maybe gave it a shot yourself and tested things on your own. Stack Overflow is meant more for debugging or when you are absolutely stumped - not for requesting things like "How should I make this thing".

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, you'd need to create a mapping of `String` to `UIColor`.

```
let colorMapping: [String: UIColor] = [
    "green": .green,
    "white": .white,
    //etc...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by mapping the text of each color to its appropriate `UIColor`:

```
let colors: [String: UIColor] = [
    // add any built-in colors
    "red": .red,
    "blue": .blue,
    // custom colors too!
    "goldenrod": UIColor(red: 218, green: 165, blue: 32) 
    // add all the colors you wish to detect
    // ...
    // ...
]
```

Make the view controller containing your text field conform to `UITextViewDelegate` and implement the `shouldChangeTextIn` function (gets called whenever the user enters/deletes a character):

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    // ... other view controller code

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

        if let currentText = textField.text {
            // check if the text is in the `colors` dictionary
            //   and if so, apply the color to the `textColor`
            if colors.keys.contains(currentText) {
                textField.textColor = colors[currentText]
            }
        }

        return true

    }

    // ... other view controller code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the text in textfield using the below delegate method

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
        //Don't forgot to make user entered content to lowercaseString while checking with colorCollection

        if colorCollection.keys.contains(textField.text.lowercaseString) {
            textField.textColor = colorCollection[currentText] //If entered content match with any colour then it will change the text colour of textfield  
        }

    return true
}
```

Create simple collection of color like below

```
let colorCollection: [String: UIColor] = [
    "blue": .blue,
    "purple": .purple,
    //your other coolers 
]
```

Answer (score 0):

So assuming you have textfield and textview outlet or created programmatically:-

```
let textField = UITextField()
let txtVw = UITextView()
 //If enter some text inside textfield for instance red then get the value, compare it and set the text color on textview
if textField.text?.lowercased() == "red" {
 txtVw.textColor = UIColor.red
}
```